# angular2-select cannot set the default value

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular2-select

Trying to use ( in angular4 ) this [angular2 select component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-select), `angular2-select`. The docs is [here](https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select/home).

The example given is working with simple variable.

```
SelectedValue = '3';
```

Data binding is working fine. ( I suppose )

But in my case, I am binding to a property of an object. Something like:

```
[(ngModel)]="eventData.event.code"
```

So if I want to set a default value in `ngInit`, it doesn't work. 
    this.eventData.event.code = "abc";

Beside setting default value, data binding using `ngModel` is working fine.

```
<ng-select 
    name="eventDataCode" 
    id="eventDataCode" 
    [options]="codeList" 
    placeholder="" 
    [(ngModel)]="eventData.event.code" required ></ng-select>

ngOnInit() {

    this.eventData = new EventData;
    this.eventData.event.code = "abc";
    console.log(this.eventData.event);// code:undefined
    console.log(this.eventData.event.code);// code:abc
}
```

Comment: some codes please ?

Comment: ok, done. added template code and some js.

Comment: Try to change the value to int by using '+' symbol  Try this: console.log(+this.eventData.event.code);// code:abc

Comment: the issue is that I can log whatever value of the property "code" of the this.eventData.event, but when I log this.eventData.event, it's "undefined". Isn't it strange?